# Convert dates to different timezones without MomentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have a quite data-heavy app I'm working on, and I can see in Chrome's profiler that `moment` is chewing up an enormous amount of CPU when working with large datasets. I'm aware it's reasonably well-known for this, but I don't know how I'd format timezones with a native `Date` object. Is it achievable?

For what it's worth, the super expensive function I've written is this:

```
export const formatByTimeZone = date => {
    const userTimezone = moment.tz.guess()

    moment.tz.setDefault('Australia/Melbourne')

    const returnValue = moment(date).tz(userTimezone)

    moment.tz.setDefault()

    return returnValue
}
```

Our API uses Melbourne time, so it just converts that to the user's time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/)

> Momentjs has his all functions as member function. So you have to import all functions even you need only ‘Add’ function. Once you create a instance, all function are included.
>   date-fns is divided by function level. So you can import and use only what you need. 
>  
>   Becuase of this reason, in result of build on web application, generally momentjs has more size than date-fns.(no tree shaking) - [more](https://medium.com/@k2u4yt/momentjs-vs-date-fns-6bddc7bfa21e)

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your function as below

```
const userTimezone = moment.tz.guess();
export const formatByTimeZone = date => {
    const returnValue = moment(date, 'Australia/Melbourne').tz(userTimezone);
    return returnValue;
}
```

1. get and set userTimezone in variable once instead of doing it everytime when formatted
2. Don't change default timezone everytime when formatted

Comment: Thanks, Santhosh. I believe the primary issue is Moment itself is rather slow compared to other packages (or native Date()). I'll give this a try, though. Thanks!